# Confusion about CSS Floats

Tags: css, css-float

I'm little confused about floats.
I have created an example for float.
http://jsbin.com/pasavifego/edit?html,css,js,output

I have given a back ground color for my ul as red.

All my li's are floating left, I dont see any background color now. If i remove the float it is working. Can someone explain why this happens.

Another questions is, When one div is float:left,when i add another div, why does it start next to that div.

Can some one please explain this.

Thanks

Comment: Because when you float something it's removed from the flow of the document. In your case the ul collapses because it doesn't see any li elements. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: Yes, all li's are floated left, but they are within ul.So,Ul can stll see the li elements, so why not background becomes red

Comment: __**Because when you float something it's removed from the flow of the document.**__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@adam-buchanan-smith's answer is a good way of doing this without floats.

But to answer your question, what's happened is the `<ul>` has no height. As @j08691's comment says, `float`ed elements take up no vertical space in their container. In this example, the second `<ul>` just shows up as a red line:

```css
ul {
  outline: 1px solid red
}
.with-floated-lis li {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>not floated</li>
</ul>

<ul class="with-floated-lis">
  <li>floated</li>
<ul>
```

The trick to get around this is called the "clearfix hack", and it's an essential tool in frontend development. When you float something and want its container to expand vertically to contain the floated element, apply the clearfix to the container:

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
ul {
  outline: 1px solid red
}
.with-floated-lis li {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<ul class="with-floated-lis clearfix">
  <li>floated, ul has clearfix</li>
</ul>
```

Nicolas Gallagher wrote that clearfix. His post is here http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/. Read more about clearfix and floats here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use `display: inline` instead of `float: left` see example https://jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/7/

And for a good beginning explanation on floated elements see here http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-floats/#What_happens_to_an_element_when_it_floats

```
li{
display:inline;
list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam... This article explains about a fix,https://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats.but i could not replicate though.I liked ur solution, which is simple

Comment: https://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/